# recursively object to ul list and add class with index in javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, counter

I have a working recursive function that creates an `<ul>` list from an object, it works fine,
my problem is that I want to keep track of the index, and add it as class to `<li>` elements,
I need that the "index count system" will count in a particular way, and **this is the output that I want**:

```
class0
    class0_0
        class0_0_0
        class0_0_1

    class0_1
        class0_1_0
        class0_1_1


class1
    class1_0
        class1_0_0
        class1_0_1

    class1_1
        class1_1_0
        class1_1_1
```

by increasing, restarting and have maybe multiple "index count" variables in the recirsive function

This is what I'm trying, but I still can't figure out where to properly set, increase, reset the counters to achieve that result..

```
var i = 0;
function object2ul(data) {
    var json = "<ul>";

    for(var key in data) {
        json = json + "<li>" +'<b>'+i+'</b>'+ key; i++;
        if(typeof data[key] == 'object') {
            json = json + object2ul(data[key]);
        }else{ i=0;
            json = json + '<ul><li>'+ data[key]+'</li></ul>';
        }
        json = json + "</li>";
    }
    return json + "</ul>";
}

document.body.innerHTML = object2ul(object);
```

In this example I omitted to set the classes avoiding to complicate the function

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ozuax6sf/)**

Comment: what is the output you want???

Comment: add a second "classPrefix" argument to your function and append the current index for each recursive call.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```js
var object = {
    root0: {
        child0: {
            leaf: 'text',
            leaf: 'text'
        },
        child1: {
            leaf: 'text',
            leaf: 'text'
        }
    },
    root1: {
        child0:{
            leaf: 'text',
            leaf: 'text'
        },
        child1: {
            leaf: 'text',
            leaf: 'text'
        }
    }
};

var i = 0;
function object2ul(data, prefix) {
    prefix = prefix || '0'; // default
    var json = "<ul>";

    var childIndex = 0;
    for(var key in data) {
        json = json + "<li>" +'<b>'+i+'</b>'+ key; i++;
        if(typeof data[key] == 'object') {
            json = json + object2ul(data[key], prefix + '_' + childIndex);
        }else{ i=0;
            json = json + '<ul><li>'+ data[key]+'---(' + prefix + ')</li></ul>';
        }
        json = json + "</li>";
        childIndex++;
    }
    return json + "</ul>";
}

document.body.innerHTML = object2ul(object);
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the kind of indexing you want, you are going to have to use Object.keys.  The following should work for an arbitrary object:

```
var testObj = { a: { b: '2', d: '5', e: { f: '3' } }, c: '3' };

var indexes = [];
var object2ul = function (data) {
    var keys = Object.keys(data);
    var json = "<ul>";
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; ++i) { 
        var key = keys[i];
        indexes.push(i);
        json += "<li>" + "<b>" + indexes.join('_') + "</b>" + key;
        if (typeof(data[key]) === 'object') {
            json += object2ul(data[key]);
        } else {
            json += "<ul><li>" + data[key] + "</li></ul>";
        }
        json += "</li>";
        indexes.pop();
    }
    return json + "</ul>";
}

document.body.innerHTML = object2ul(testObj);
```

Here's it in action:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v6qtcuLy/)

Comment: I am trying to create a bootstrap accordion, to do it I need to pass some id also to the ul parents, I almost finished it and I am very close to the final solution, my only problem is that actually It repeats the first step one time with another "0" instead to became "0_0", but only at the very first step! other are fine. please have a look http://jsfiddle.net/hhpb24fr/ I mean the new "level" variable, hope you will understand